# What is the relationship between LuaTex and TeXLive here?

Tags: luatex, texlive

Here is what happens when I type in terminal.

```
$ luatex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
```

What is the relationship between [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/) and [TeXLive](https://tug.org/texlive/) here?

Here's what I could find:

> TeX Live is an easy (we hope) way to get up and running with the TeX document production system. It provides a comprehensive TeX system with binaries for most flavors of Unix, including GNU/Linux, macOS, and also Windows. It includes all the major TeX-related programs, macro packages, and fonts that are free software, including support for many languages around the world.

and also for LuaTeX, suggests there's even another type involved XeTeX:

> LuaTeX is an extended version of pdfTeX using Lua as an embedded
>   scripting language. The LuaTeX project's main objective is to provide
>   an open and configurable variant of TeX while at the same time
>   offering downward compatibility. From the user perspective we have
>   pdfTeX as stable and more or less frozen 8 bit engine, XeTeX as
>   unicode input and font aware engine using libraries for font handling,

Now we have that LuaTeX is running with TeX Live so I am just trying to understand how the different parts interact.

Comment: TeX Live is the distribution, LuaTeX the engine. So, LuaTeX is contained in TeX Live as are all packages needed to compile. LuaTeX does the actual compilation.

Comment: texlive package and distribute a diverse collection of programs fonts and files to make a useable system.  As you are a debian user, you could compare it to debian making a coherent thing out of a linux kernel and thousands of other programs by other authors, plus some glue and packaging done at Debian.